# Joda-Time confusion for converting DateTimeField to text/String

Tags: android, jodatime, localtime

I have a `Joda` `DateTimeField` object called `startTime` which is a `LocalTime`. Meaning it contains an hour (ranging 0-23), a minute, (0-59), and a second (0-59).

Now when I call the method:
`startTime.getChronology().hourOfDay().getAsShortText(int fieldValue, Locale l)`
I get a bit confused; the `Locale` I understand but when I look up the `DateTimeField` API [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeField.html#getAsShortText(int,%20java.util.Locale))
there is not really any explanation as to what I should input for the fieldValue.

Is there a document describing which integers refer to which fieldValue?

Now; I've already tried just doing `startTime.getChronology().hourOfDay().toString()` which does not work. it merely returns this text: `DateTimeField[hourOfDay]`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation link you have yourself given, the argument `fieldValue` is just described as numerical value of the associated field. In your case, it is the hour-of-day-value, hence any number between 0 and 23.

As far as I know, the method `getAsShortText(...)` will not really produce text for the hour-of-day, but just yield the digits in string-form. This method is rather designed for fields which really have a special text form like months or weekdays. Example demonstrating the triviality of your approach (the code is meaningless for any use case):

```
LocalTime time = new LocalTime(14, 45, 30);
String text = time.getChronology().hourOfDay().getAsShortText(12, Locale.FRENCH);
System.out.println("Hour-of-day 12 as text: " + text);
// output: Hour-of-day 12 as text: 12
```

Maybe you are confused because you have the field constants in JDK-class `java.util.Calendar` in mind, but there the field constants denote field identifiers, not field values. The same function (namely identifying fields) is achieved by `DateTimeField`-objects in Joda-Time.